# Conversion from binary string to decimal?

Tags: c

In the following code I am converting a binary to decimal and then printing the character corresponding to it.

```
void convertToChar(int binaryChar[],int length)
{
int multiplier = 0;
int i;
int sum = 0;
for(i=length;i>=0;i++)
{
    sum = sum + (binaryChar[i]*pow(2,multiplier));
    multiplier = multiplier + 1;
}
printf("\nThe character is: %c",sum);
}
```

The problem is in the line `sum = sum + (binaryChar[i]*pow(2,multiplier));` .It throws the error:  `warning: converting to`int' from `double'`.Please help!

Comment: when converting from double to int your number can get truncated (use the same type -> use double)

Comment: You're converting from a binary string (eg "1010101"), right?  I added "string" to the question title since that's a better description of what you want to do.  Though actually converting from binary string to binary.

Comment: i am not converting from double to int all my data types are integer

Comment: @Octpus: that's a horrible answer, you just want to blindly fix the problem by observing the warning. you should read the code.

Comment: Also, don't use `pow(2,..)`, use bitwise arithmetic, it's faster and cleaner.  (the reason you're getting complaints about doubles is because `pow()` uses double as arguments and return value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using `pow` to calculate a power of 2? It's too slow. Use `1 << p` to get the p-th power of two. E.g., `1 << 0` will give 1, `1 << 1` will give 2, `1 << 2` will give 4. This is due to the nature of the bit shift operation: shifting one bit to the left is equivalent of multiplying by 2.

Also, it looks like you have an endless cycle in your program:

```
for(i=length;i>=0;i++)
```

If `length` is >= 0, the loop will never terminate.

This should fix it:

```
for(i = length - 1; i>=0; i--) sum += (binaryChar[i]*(1 << multiplier++));
```

Comment: Actually the loop **will** terminate but only after the int type has wrapped around to negative. Before that the program is probably going to hit invalid memory access. :)

Answer (score 2):

the signature of `pow` is:

```
double pow(double X, double Y);
```

for calculating 2^multiplier use:

```
1 << multiplier;
```

Just to quickly mention:

- You have an infinite loop
- If you parse the string from the other direction you can multiply the sum by two so you don't need the `multiplier` variable.
- After that many problems I'm not even sure that `int binaryChar[]` is right. Char in the name suggests a different type (and code)..

.

Comment: Unfortunately that's only one of the many problems with the code.

Answer (score 1):

pow takes doubles and returns a double.  An ugly fix is just to use a cast

```
(int)pow(x, y)
```

But in this simple program, why not just do the power expansion yourself instead of calling pow?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the precision of the data type int is smaller as the precision of double (the function [pow](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/) returns double) therefore the value of binaryChar[i] will be implizit converted to double and so on... problematic line implicit looks like this:

```
sum = (double) sum + ((double) binaryChar[i] * pow((double)2, (double) multiplier))
```

in order to get rid of the warning you have to do an explicit conversion (
see [Type Conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)), e.g.:

```
sum = sum + (binaryChar[i] * ((int) pow(2, multiplier));
```